# How can I "amplify" current motion ?

Tags: unity

I've two objects A and B. A impact B causing B movement.

I want programmatically "amplify" B movement mantaining B resulting direction.

I've try adding a script like this

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    // Controllo se è un tag 
    if (_forceAlreadyApplied==false) {

        _rb.AddForce (_forcePower * transform.forward, ForceType);
        _forceAlreadyApplied = true;

    }
}
```

The problem is that transform.forward obviously change B direction.

Maybe this is a wrong approach.

My question is: how to "amplify" current speed ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved using (and multiplying) RigidBody.velocity.

Example:

```
void Update() {
    if (_activated && ApplyForTimer  > 0) {
        _rb.velocity = _rb.velocity * _forcePower;
        ApplyForTimer  = ApplyForTimer  - Time.deltaTime;

    }
}
```